# HttpContent, HTTPResponseMessage cannot be resolved - imported to the ASP project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2013, httpresponse

I wanted to create project following that tutorial: http://www.strathweb.com/2013/01/asynchronously-streaming-video-with-asp-net-web-api/

I created Web Application in Visual Studio 2013. Copied the code from the tutorial, and I there is no `resolve->using` in the pop-up menu for some elements, like: `HttpContent`, `HTTPResponseMessage`. I do not know which references I am lacking. Why there is a problem?

[image]

**EDIT**:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultVideo",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{ext}/{filename}"
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yoda,

It appears you have a standard `WebApplication`. The code you copied and pasted is for `MVC Web API Applications`.

Close the solution and create a new project selecting `New-> New Project` from the Projects menu select `Visual C# -> Web -> ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application` such as the image below.

[image]

When you select the `ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application` you will be given the option to select the type of project. From the list select `Web Api`.

Now in-order to use the `async` modifier you must re-target your project. Right click on the Project name in the `Soltion Explorer` and select `Properties`. From the properties sheet select the `Application` tab and change the `Target Framework` to `.NET Framework 4.5` and save clicking `Yes` to the project.

[image]

Once you have done that simply add your new `VideoStream` class and copy paste the code. You will have the context menu of `Resolve ->  using...`. For your information you must add the following `using` statements.

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
```

**EDIT:**

Additional answer based on edit.
The code snipped in your edit is used to *Map Routes*. Add this code to the file located

`/App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs`

There will already be a default entry. Your end result would look like..

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultVideo",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{ext}/{filename}"
        );
        config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. Do you know where to add the code from the edit? It does not look like C# and there is no mentioning where it should go.(It is my firs .ASP app)

Comment: I AM SORRY. By mistake I edited your post, not mine.

Comment: No problem. The edit has been cancelled (rejected).. Glad it worked for you.